# You are not authorized to view this page

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, web-config, webserver

I am getting the following error while browsing my asp.net page deployed in IIS

```
You are not authorized to view this page
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please try the following:

Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page. 
Click the Refresh button to try again with different credentials. 
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Technical Information (for support personnel)

Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search for the words HTTP and 401. 
Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Authentication, Access Control, and About Custom Error Messages.
```

I have checked the NTFS permissions in the website and found that everyone group has read and execute privilege.

But there is no IUSER group for the folder

anonymous access configured in this folder and no integrated authentication enabled.

Comment: have a look in the server's event log/iis logs to see exactly what's happening with that request. you shouldn't enable anonymous access on your web app if the web config is using windows authentication.

Comment: yes my webpage is using windows authentication

Comment: is it okay to remove "everyone" group and add iuser and untick anonymous access and integrated authentication

Comment: if you're using windows authentication, you should disable all other authentications but Windows Authentication in IIS. The file system permissions don't really need to differ from the defaults...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added appropriate permissions to the files in the wwwroot.

The easiest way to do this is to right click on the wwwroot folder in Explorer and then click *Properties*. Then on the Security tab, click the Advanced button. On the next pop-up check the "Replace permissions on all child objects" box and click Apply.

OK out of all the dialogs and give your site another try.

Comment: i have active directory retrieval from website ..is that causing the issue?